# Show the connecting user login status using Websocket and Pusher

Tags: php, pusher

I'm building a chat room web application using Pusher for the first time. I read a lot in the documentation of Pusher to learn how it works. My question is more about mechanism and not about code.

So what I want to do is, when a user connects and joins the `presence-channel` which allows me to display who is online. I want to display a status sign (Green = online, yellow = away) for the user (like Skype) and all the logged users can see the change between status in real time.

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27375125/pusher-one-to-one-chat-structure) and if I understand, each user must join a private-channel to manage better its client-event. So how can I manage the changing status event for the `private-channel` and show it in the `presence-channel` or how can I make a communication between the two channels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a separate channel in order to build user status.

The best way to achieve this right now would be to detect user status using something like [idle.js](https://github.com/shawnmclean/Idle.js) and then trigger an event on the presence channel (maybe `client-status-updated`) with information about the user status (e.g. `{"user_id":SOME_ID, "status":"away"}`).

*Note: for client events the `client-` prefix is required on the event name*

You can do this using [client events](https://pusher.com/docs/client_events) and this can be done on the existing existing presence channels. However, you should be aware that by using client events it means any authenticated user could potentially trigger a status event and suggest it is for another user altogether. So, it would be more secure to do this via the server that can set the even it coming from the user who's status is being set.

However, I don't really see the benefit of the "hack" to set another user's status.

Here's an example using the presence channel and client events.

```
<script src="libs/idle.js"></script>
<script src="//js.pusher.com/2.2/pusher.min.js"></script>
<script>
var pusher = new Pusher(APP_KEY);
var presence = pusher.subscribe('presence-online');

// Basic online/offline
presence.bind('pusher:subscription_succeeded', function(members) {
  members.each(addUser);
});

presence.bind('pusher:member_added', addUser);
presence.bind('pusher:member_removed' removeUser);

function addUser(member) {
  // Online - add to UI
}

function removeUser(member) {
  // Offline - remove from UI
  // Consider doing this in a setTimeout
  // in case the user comes back online again
}

// User state
var idle = new Idle({
  onHidden:    function() { sendUserStatus('hidden'); },
  onVisible:   function() { sendUserStatus('visible'); },
  onAway:      function() { sendUserStatus('away'); },
  onAwayBack:  function() { sendUserStatus('hidden'); },
  awayTimeout: 30000 //away with 30 seconds of inactivity
}).start();

function sendUserStatus(status) {
  var userStatusUpdate = {
    "user_id": presence.members.me.id, // current user unique ID
    "status": status
  };
  presence.trigger('client-status-updated', userStatusUpdate);
}

presence.bind('client-status-updated', function(update) {
  var userId = update.user_id;
  var status = user.status;
  // Update UI to reflect user status
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the share leggetter. I'll seen what i can do with this informations