# Call function when PHP-page gets closed

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Is there a way to call a function when the php-page gets closed?
I am saving the online/offline status in my MySQL db.
With my function

```
Users::isOffline(Users::getUserName())
```

I'm writing "offline" into the db.
Now I want to call this function when someone is closing the page with the close button.
I've tried this:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
function confirmExit()
{
var offline= <?php echo Users::isOffline(Users::getUserName())?>;
}
</script>
```

But then, the function gets called when the php-page is loaded....
Any ideas? :)

Comment: Just curious, any reason you are not using something like a last_activity time? is it a game? or...?

Comment: @ChrisBanks No, its a website with an filebrowser on it. I am using a last_activity_time... but I also wanna use the online/offline status :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it because php could be executed on **backend**, you can achieve desired result in next ways:

**Preferable**

If you need to do it in right way see **@Philip Andersson** answer.
Also you could get an clear idea of how to use websockets in [Create Live Group Tutorial](https://subinsb.com/live-group-chat-with-php-jquery-websocket).

**Workaround**

What you want to achieve can be done by applying next steps:

1. create php file which would perform `Users::isOffline(Users::getUserName())` while handling request from your browser
2. Create javascript handler **onbeforeunload**, which would send [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) request to newly created php file mentioned before.

*Tricky moment:* It's not trivial way to send **Ajax Request** from `onbeforeunload` handler. To do it use code provided below:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    var x = sendUserOfflineAjax();
    return x;
};

function sendUserOfflineAjax(){
        // Perform sending ajax request
}
```

Comment: I tried this : `<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    var x = sendUserOfflineAjax();
    return x;
};

function sendUserOfflineAjax(){
        xhttp.open("GET", "logout.php?name=<?php echo User::getUserName(); ?>", true);
xhttp.send();
}
    </script>` But it doesnt work ...

Comment: Ok, I had another mistake with my including of AJAX. Your solution with sending an AJAX request works very well. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It is because PHP code doesn't run on client side - you need to use JS.

```
function confirmExit(){
//here you send request to your server
}
```

And on serverside you recieve request and mark user as offline

Comment: But when I send the request in this javascript function, I have to open a new db connection and stuff like that. Thats what I not wanted to to ... Thats why I wrote my Users class

Comment: @npit java != javascript

Comment: @npit you can use your class method while recieving request from JS `confirmExit`

Comment: @ManasovDaniel Can you explain this a little bit more ? How should this look like?

Comment: @npit as Thomas sais Java is not JavaScript, like tea is not teapot

Comment: @npit you can invoke `Users::isOffline(Users::getUserName())` when you got request. I don't know what is inside your app so I can't explain more ;)

Comment: @ManasovDaniel Ah now I get what you think... It is already JS `<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">`

Comment: @npit yeah, that's right. But my comment was about you said Java in first comment. It's little bit offensive for JS-developers when people say Java instead JavaScript :D

Comment: @ManasovDaniel yeah, that was my fault ^^ just forgot the script behind it. But I corrected it :)

Answer (score 2):

What you try to achieve is not that easy using only php and javascript.
Usually when you want to have a good online/offline status check you will have to use websockets.

There is a free subscription service called [Pusher](http://pusher.com), i have used it many times and it's very easy to setup.

And also, here you can read how to set it up for online/offline:
[Show the connecting user login status using Websocket and Pusher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29130593/show-the-connecting-user-login-status-using-websocket-and-pusher)

Answer (score 2):

You can post user's information to another php file before page close.

Button would be like this:

```
<button type='button' data-userid='<?php echo Users::isOffline(Users::getUserName())?>'>click1</button>
```

You can post userid to a php file to update the status.

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var userid = $(this).attr('data-userid';
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "gooffline.php",
      data: {userid: userid},
      success: function(data)
      {
          alert("Come back soon!");
      }
   });
});
```

Php file would be like this:

```
$userid = $_POST["userid"];
$status = userLoggingOut($userid); //your db update function
if($status){
    echo json_encode(array("status"=>"success","message"=>"user info updated"));
}
```

Hope this solves.