# Private one to one chat structure with pusher

Tags: php, yii, pusher

I've implement chat with pusher and it works fine. But the problem is everyone can see it, there is no restriction to hide or make it private. How to make it private one to one chat room that other users can't able to see their conversations. I've call widget like this:

```
jQuery(function() {     
        var pusher = new Pusher("MY_APP_KEY" , { authEndpoint: '/pusher_auth.php' })
        var chatWidget = new PusherChatWidget(pusher, {
          appendTo: "#pusher_chat_widget"
        });
      });
```

and in pusher_auth.php

```
global $user;
if ($user->uid)
{
  $pusher = new Pusher(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, APP_ID);
  echo $pusher->socket_auth($_POST['channel_name'], $_POST['socket_id']);
}
else
{
  header('', true, 403);
  echo "Forbidden";
}
```

so please tell me how its possible,
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! None of the code you posted has anything to with securing a chat room. Can you share what you have tried regarding that?

Comment: I am new to real time world so can you please explain the procedure for having a private chat.I will implement that and if still i will get a problem then i will post you the code. Thanks

Comment: That is not how SO works, that is much too broad a question. You'll need to do some actual research and coding. If you have issues with your code were are here to help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pusher one to one chat structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27375125/pusher-one-to-one-chat-structure)

Comment: Hi @JayBlanchard , i am new in this pusher programing please tell me what you want to know about my code i can provide you my code file...please tell me your email id...please help me to create my app

Comment: hi leggetter,                                                                                                            i was trying to implement your solution that you answered in another almost same question. i have faced one problem with that. When i tried to call trigger function in my javascript file.                                  pusher.trigger( channels, 'one-to-one-chat-request', eventData );                      It returns : TypeError: pusher.trigger is not a function, have any idea to solve this ??