# Pusher: Peer to Peer chat

Tags: javascript, jquery, sockets, laravel, pusher

### I'm trying to make a platform where there is a list of users, When user-A clicks on user-B a chat between the two should be initialised.

So I'm wondering what the best method would be to go about this..
For the moment I've come up with this.

#### Every user enters the presence-channel.

#### Every user get's it's own private-notications-channel

- ( private-notifications-A, private-notifications-B, ... )

But now I'm stuck, Should I create a **private-chat-userA-userB** channel?
Do I even need the notifications channel?

This is my PHP code that create's the private channel

```
public function chat(PusherManager $pusher, Request $request)
{
    $sender = Auth::user()->id;
    $receiver = (int) $request->get('id');

    if($sender !== $receiver)
    {
        $data = [
            "sender" => Auth::user(),
            "receiver" => User::find($receiver)
        ];

        $pusher->trigger("private-chat-".$sender . "-" . $receiver, "message", $data);
    }
}
```

> So I'm wondering how do I subscribe the 2 users to the
> private-chat-channel for them?

Comment: is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27375125/pusher-one-to-one-chat-structure ?

Comment: Did you found a solution or any reference link that helped you?

Comment: Hello thread from the past, It's been 4 years so I don't even remember. I'm sure the pusher and laravel syntax has changed a lot as well. Good luck!