# Java Server Pusher Chat: needs Architecture for Pusher one to one chat on java server as well as android

Tags: java, android, web-services, jax-rs, pusher

I need Architecture for **Pusher** android and Java Server Side Implementation for One to One chat.

below is android code this is working fine and i am getting `auth` also.

```
  {"event":"pusher:subscribe","data":{"auth":"9272f25541ab7b04fc60:e146b0b663fdfe276af5e4d45de6db7db272bd103414cc9525b998c5eff35268","channel_data":"{\"user_id\":\"12345\",\"user_info\":{\"name\":\"Phil Leggetter\",\"twitterId\":\"@leggetter\"}}","channel":"presence-channel"}}
```

**And Android code here:**

```
final HttpAuthorizer authorizer = new HttpAuthorizer(Constant.BASE_URL_BHARTI + "initial/pusher/auth");
    //authorizer.setHeaders(getMapAuthorizationHeaders());
    PusherOptions options = new PusherOptions().setAuthorizer(authorizer);
    final Pusher pusher = new Pusher("9272f25541ab7b04fc60", options);

    pusher.connect(new com.pusher.client.connection.ConnectionEventListener() {


        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(ConnectionStateChange connectionStateChange) {

            Log.e("connectionStateChange", connectionStateChange.getCurrentState().toString());

            if (connectionStateChange.getCurrentState() == ConnectionState.CONNECTED) {

                SOCKET_ID = pusher.getConnection().getSocketId();
                Log.e("SOCKET_ID", "" + SOCKET_ID);

                channel = pusher.subscribePresence("presence-channel", new PresenceChannelEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onUsersInformationReceived(String channelName, Set<User> users) {
                        Log.e("PUSHER", "" + channelName + "  " + new Gson().toJsonTree(users));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void userSubscribed(String channelName, User user) {
                        Log.e("PUSHER", "Channel userSubscribed authorization succeeded  " + channelName);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void userUnsubscribed(String channelName, User user) {
                        Log.e("PUSHER", "Channel userUnsubscribed authorization err  " + channelName);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAuthenticationFailure(String message, Exception e) {
                        Log.e("PUSHER", "Channel subscription authorization failed  " + e);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSubscriptionSucceeded(String channelName) {
                        Log.e("PUSHER", "Channel subscription authorization succeeded  " + channelName);
                        CHANELNAME = channelName;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(String channelName, String eventName, String data) {
                        Log.e("PUSHER", "An event with name " + eventName + " was delivered!!" + "  " + data + "  " + channelName);
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        Message message = gson.fromJson(data, Message.class);
                        try {
                            messageAdapter.add(message);
                            messagesView.setSelection(messageAdapter.getCount() - 1);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("Exception", "" + e);
                        }
                    }
                },"my-event");
```

Now i need java server side code implementation for one to one chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take reference from here [Pusher one to one chat structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27375125/pusher-one-to-one-chat-structure?rq=1)

1st requirement for java server side implementation you have to add dependency in `pom.xml`.

```
      <dependency>
           <groupId>com.pusher</groupId>
           <artifactId>pusher-http-java</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
```

AND

```
       <dependency>
             <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
             <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
             <version>4.3.5</version>
       </dependency>
```

Otherwise you will get `500 error`

If you are **using JAX-RS web services along with Presence Channel** then your `/pusher/auth` service can be written as:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Path("/pusher/auth")
public String processMessagesAndAuthentication( MultivaluedMap<String, String> input){
    Pusher pusher = new Pusher("APP-ID", "PUSHER-KEY", "PUSHER-SECRET-KEY");
    String userId = "12345"; //any unique id
    Map<String, String> userInfo = new HashMap<>();
    userInfo.put("name", "Bharti Rawat");
    userInfo.put("twitterId", "@leggetter");
    String socket_id = input.getFirst("socket_id");
    String channel_name = input.getFirst("channel_name");
    String auth = pusher.authenticate(socket_id, channel_name, new PresenceUser(userId, userInfo));
    return auth;
}
```

Comment: please explain more about it